# List of characters to table in R

Tags: r

I have a list of objects of class character. In this list, there are supposed to be four classes: class SN N, class S F, class S SN, and class S N F. Notice these are not all the same length.

```
> list1
[[1]]
[1] "SN" "N"      

[[2]]
[1] "S"  "F"

[[3]]
[1] "S"      "SN"

[[4]]
[1] "S" "N" "F"

[[5]]
[1] "SN" "N"
```

How can I get a table out of this? I'd like a count of the number of times each class appears in the data set. This is the error I'm getting:

```
> table(list1)
Error in table(list1) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: @akrun I think the "elements" consist of combinations. Maybe `paste` each list element together first, then unlist and call table? Like `sapply(list1,paste,collapse = " ")` and then `table`?

Comment: Thanks @joran, that did the trick!

Comment: What if I have the above, and also have "N" "SN", which I don't want to be a distinct class from "SN" "N"?

Comment: @StatsSorceress  Sort them before pasting?